# Messaging.renderemailtemplate() fails with error: System.EmailTemplateRenderException: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: apex, trigger, email, exception

I am trying to render an email using the method: Messaging.renderemailtemplate(), by passing three parameters: templateId,whoId ( user ) ,whatId ( Custom Object ) from a Trigger.

The insertion of the custom record and calling the method: renderemailtemplate() happens in the same transaction, but I get the error:

`System.EmailTemplateRenderException: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Code:

```
public static void emailMethodName(Id templateId, sObject who, sObject what)
{
...
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = 
Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId,(Id)who.get('Id'), (Id)what.get('Id')); // I get the error in this line.
...
}
```

This method is called from a trigger handler Class in the after update context.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: can you check all the fields referenced in the template are populated for that record?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal , Yes I have put a debug statement just before the method call and indeed all the three values are set.

Comment: Is it a Visualforce template?

Comment: I have seen this happen when fields are null...can you populate them and try again?

Comment: @DavidReed yes, it is a visualforce template

Comment: @PranayJaiswal What do you mean by populate them again? In debug logs I have checked that all the parameter values are set, before the method is called.

Comment: Can you put more code snippet?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal updated the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having extensive discussion with Salesforce.com, the conclusion is that the method: Messaging.renderemailtemplate() rechecks, if the running user have at least Read Permission to the object being sent as a parameter. The error mentioned above is shown if the permission is not / cannot be configured.

Comment: Yes, I learned this myself as well, and this is a huge oversight on SF’s part!